# Error while pushing Dates to Array in Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, datejs

This is the function (I feel I did the same thing a few hours ago and the output was what I was expecting)

```
function errorFunction() {
  let master = []

  let a = [1,2] //a simple array to loop over

  a.forEach(function(b) {
    let theDate = Date.today() // 8th Sep 2021
    let i = 0
    while (i<2) {
      theDate = Date.parse(theDate).addDays(1)
      Logger.log(theDate) // dates are alternating between 9th and 10th september
      master.push([b,i,theDate])

      i = i+1
    }

  })
  
  Logger.log(master) // all dates are 10th september
}
```

The code is pushing 9th September and 10th September to the array. But the output of the array has only 10th September.

What I expect :

```
[
  [1.0, 0.0, Fri Sep 9 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2021],
  [1.0, 1.0, Fri Sep 10 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2021],
  [2.0, 0.0, Fri Sep 9 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2021],
  [2.0, 1.0, Fri Sep 10 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2021]
]
```

The Output I get :

```
[
  [1.0, 0.0, Fri Sep 10 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2021],
  [1.0, 1.0, Fri Sep 10 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2021],
  [2.0, 0.0, Fri Sep 10 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2021],
  [2.0, 1.0, Fri Sep 10 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2021]
]
```

I am using the latest version of DateJs library.

Comment: A couple more details,please. What are `a` and `b`? What is `Date.today()`, the 9th or the 10th of September?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass a `Date` object to the `parse()` method of **DateJS**, it will return the object ([link](https://github.com/datejs/Datejs/blob/56b945cf4ebb6b8eb6404c47697bd518e3d413b0/src/parser.js#L1068)), and the `addDate()` method also does not create a new object ([link](https://github.com/datejs/Datejs/blob/56b945cf4ebb6b8eb6404c47697bd518e3d413b0/src/core.js#L261)). So while you created a new `theDate` object for every `b` value, you modified the *same* object in the `while` loop, and put references to it into the `master` array.

The solution is to create a new `Date` object every time you modify `theDate`. For example, change this line:

```js
theDate = Date.parse(theDate).addDays(1)
```

...to this:

```js
theDate = new Date(theDate.valueOf()).addDays(1)
```

...or this (DateJS defines a `clone()` method):

```js
theDate = theDate.clone().addDays(1)
```

This will clone the `theDate` object before adding 1 day to it.

Comment: this doesn't seem to be cloning the date. I tried doing this but it doesn't work.

Comment: Fixed the explanation and the code. I tried the code in `https://script.google.com/` and it works for me (I get the "9, 10, 9, 10").

Comment: Actually `clone()` returns `new Date(this.getTime())` which is the same as `new Date(this.valueOf())`, but using `clone()` instead makes the code much more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you need that library, this snippet does the job:

```js
const errorFunction = () => {
  const days = [1, 2];
  const i = [0, 1];
  const today = new Date();
  const addDays = (date, numDays = 1) =>
    new Date(new Date().setDate(date.getDate() + numDays));
  return days.reduce((acc, day) => {
    return [...acc, ...i.map(item => [day, item, addDays(today, day)])];
  }, []);
};

console.log(errorFunction());
```

Let me know if this is what you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

As @kol pointed out that I was putting references in the Array.

So instead of a reference, I did this :

```
function errorFunction() {
  let master = []

  let a = [1,2] //a simple array to loop over

  a.forEach(function(b) {
    let theDate = Date.today() // 8th Sep 2021
    let i = 0
    while (i<2) {
      theDate = Date.parse(theDate).addDays(1)
      Logger.log(theDate) // dates are alternating between 9th and 10th september
      master.push([b,i,new Date(theDate)])

      i = i+1
    }

  })
  
  Logger.log(master) // all dates are 10th september
}
```